# Is it possible to insert option tags in a select tag from ajax html

Tags: jquery, html, xml, ajax

I have a url which returns a bunch of options tags.  Can I stick that in my $.ajax success:

```
function(html) {

}
```

Can I push all the option tags directly inside my select tag after emptying my select tag.
my select tag has a name of "SelectName".
I was thinking something like so:

```
$("select[name='selectName']").appendTo($(html));   // but this doesn't work
```

my html looks like this (its nothing but option tags and it comes from a url options.apsx:

```
<option id="1">test1</option><option id="2">test2</option>...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing you are looking for `append()`

```
$("select[name='selectName']").append(html);
```

Using `appendTo` is trying to append the select list to your `<options/>` which is backwards to what you want to happen.

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrFTx/).

Comment: Wow it works Thanks!  But it also seems to hit the error: section of my ajax becuase I have an alert("error message");  right before the success:  It Fires the alert, but still populates the select.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could put something like this into your success function:

```
$("select[name='selectName']").empty();
$(html).appendTo("select[name='selectName']");
```

Assuming that `html` is the set of `option` tags returned by the function.

Comment: @Marc, yep: but trust me, we've **all** done that, or something far, far sillier, at least once... =D

Answer (score 0):

Solution Proposed: Pure JavaScript AJAX Solution

```
 //HTML
 <select id="category">
     <option value="0">--Please Select Category--</option>
 </select>  

 //Javascript onload Event
 <script> 
 window.onload = function(){
    var cat  = document.getElementById('category');     
    loadCat(cat);
 };  

 //Function that will assign Category to Element
 function loadCat(element)
     var e = element;
     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     var url = 'load_categories.php';
     xhr.open('GET',url, true);
     xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
     if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        var r = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        for (var key in r) {
            if (r.hasOwnProperty(key)) {                
                var tempNode = document.createElement("option");                    
                tempNode.value = r[key];                    
                var textnode = document.createTextNode(r[key]);                     
                tempNode.appendChild(textnode);                   
                e.appendChild(tempNode);    
            }
        }
    }
    };
   xhr.send();
 }  
 </script>
```

Server must return a basic JSON Object. The above example will work with the server JSON Response:

```
 //JSON RESPONSE FROM SERVER
 {"1":"Module","2":"Essential","3":"Security","4":"Improvement"}
```

[image: Insert Category by AJAX CALL]

Node Credit goes to the link below:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp